# Microsoft Access SQL STDEV of COUNT of data

Tags: sql, subquery, ms-access-2010

I have a table in MS Access 2010 I'm trying to analyze of people who belong to various groups having completed various jobs.  What I would like to do is calculate the standard deviation of the count of the number of jobs each person has completed per group.  Meaning, the output I would like is that for each group, I'd have a number that constitutes the standard deviation of how many jobs each person did.

The data is structured like this:

```
OldGroup, OldPerson, JobID
```

I know that I need to do a `COUNT` of the job IDs by Group and Person.  I tried creating a subquery to work with, but that didn't work:

```
SELECT data.OldGroup, STDEV(
     SELECT COUNT(data.JobID)
     FROM data
     WHERE data.Classification = 1
     GROUP BY data.OldGroup, data.OldPerson
  )
FROM data
GROUP BY data.OldGroup;
```

This returned an error "At most one record can be returned by this subquery," which I know is wrong, since when I tried to run the subquery as a standalone query it successfully returned more than one record.

**Question:**
How can I get the `STDEV` of a `COUNT`?

**Subquestion:** If this question can be answered by correcting incorrect syntax in my examples, please do so.

Comment: It is telling you that you can only return one item (the STDEV), but you are `GROUPING BY`.  Remove the `GROUP BY` from the Subquery, and see if that works.

Comment: @SableFoste, upon removing the `GROUP BY` from the subquery, Access did physically run the query, but the output is definitely not the right result--it returned a record for every `OldGroup` with the same calculation for every record as the `STDEV`.  Obviously, the different groups should not have identical standard deviations, so clearly something went wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor change in strategy that wouldn't work for all cases but did end up working for this one seemed to take care of the problem.  Instead of sticking the subquery in the `SELECT` statement, I put it in `FROM`, mimicking creating a separate table.

As such, my code looks like:

```
SELECT OldGroup, STDEV(NumberJobs) AS JobsStDev
FROM (
    SELECT OldGroup, OldPerson, COUNT(JobID) AS NumberJobs
    FROM data
    WHERE data.Classification = 1
    GROUP BY OldGroup, OldPerson
) AS TempTable
GROUP BY OldGroup;
```

That seemed to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a max table query for "SELECT COUNT(data.JobID)...."
Then for the 2nd query, use the new base table.
Sometimes it is just easier to do something in 2 or more queries.

Comment: That's what I've done for now, but since I have to run like 100 of these, I was hoping for a subquery-based solution.  Since this unfortunately is in Access (which has much more limited SQL functionality), I can't as easily have piles of temporary tables/variables lying around.

Comment: If this code is being written in VBA, you can dynamically write the SQL to create a table of a random name, say a Guid. So you'd create the table, give it a unique name so that other code/users don't clash, drop the table when you are done with it.

Comment: Normally (like with SQL Server) that can all be done straight up in SQL.  Is there no way to do that with Access, or does it all have to be in VBA?  I'd really rather not touch VBA if I don't have to.